# How to make the table non breaking using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I am having a table

```
  PdfPTable tblSummary = new PdfPTable(1);
```

And it does have 2 tables nested within it. How can I make the `tblSummary` to appear as a whole (the rows must not break to another page) or entire table be shifted to another page if it doesn't fits in the current page.

I have tried `SplitLate` and `SplitRows`

And my code is like this

```
PdfPTable tblSummary = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell csummarycell = new PdfPCell();  
PdfPTable tblSummaryFirst = new PdfPTable(3);
.
.
csummarycell.AddElement(tblSummaryFirst);
.
.
tblSummary.AddCell(csummarycell);
tblSummary.SplitLate = true;
tblSummary.SplitRows = false;
```

like this I add up one more table(s) to the tblSummary while the resulting table height is always less than that of pagesize so there is certainty that the table's content won't be more than the page height.

Any suggestions would be really helping.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
tblSummary.KeepTogether = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I didn't tried it earlier, it works great.

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you. This was awesome. This works with PDFPTable using document.Add(pdfptable) method.

Answer (score 1):

```
PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(2);
float[] anchosTablaTituloDescripcion = new float[] { 4f, 4f };
tabla.SetWidths(anchosTablaTituloDescripcion);
tabla.WidthPercentage = 100;
tabla.KeepTogether = true;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this would help and what the problem is.